# Docker build pytest :Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, docker, pytest

I am facing a serious issue while docker build.
The pytest is not working but after build(remove the pytest part) the same pytest work from inside container

Here is my docker file:

```
    FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.22

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git libaio1 libffi-dev libjpeg-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev python-wand libmagickwand-dev\
        libxslt-dev libz-dev  python3-pip python3-setuptools unzip


    ADD requirements.pip /
    RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.pip

    VOLUME ["/app"]
    WORKDIR /app
    ADD . .


    EXPOSE 8000
    RUN python3  manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
    RUN python3  -m pytest tests/test_demo.py
```

Here is my test file:

```
    import requests

    def test_demo():
        response = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:8000/' + "demo")
        assert (response.status_code == 200)
```

Please help.

Comment: `RUN python3  manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &` will not do what you expect it to do. Each `RUN` instruction is executed as its own container; once conpleted, the container stops and changes are written in a separate layer of the built image. So, the server starts, but the `RUN` command exits immediately, so the cobtainer is stopped, the layer is committed, and a new container starts for running `pytest` command, with no Django server running.

Comment: Suggestion: rather than reinventing the wheel, why not use `pytest-django` which will start the server automatically when you run `pytest`? It will also stop the server once the test execution completes, and provides a lot of goodies that help you avoid boilerplate code. Just install `pytest-django` and run your tests via `pytest --ds=my.settings.module` to trigger it.

Comment: `pytest-django`  is  also not working : `pytest .tests/test_demo.py --ds=my_project.settings`

Comment: "why not use pytest-django which will start the server automatically when you run pytest" please confirm that it start the server automatically

Comment: _pytest-django is also not working_ - what error do you get?

Comment: The same error. I don't think pytest-django will restart the server

Comment: @hoefling any help for server start??

Comment: See my answer for a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example of tests ran with `pytest-django` in container build stage.

#### the test script

```python
# test_server.py
import requests


def test_about_page(live_server):
    response = requests.get(live_server.url + '/about')
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Notice I used the [`live_server`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#live-server) fixture that starts a separate server instance in another thread. I can then access the address via `live_server.url` in the test.

Similarly, the changes needed to be done in your test would then be:

```python
import requests

def test_demo(live_server):
    response = requests.get(live_server.url + "/demo")
    assert (response.status_code == 200)
```

#### the sample `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update && apt install git python3-pip -y \
    && pip3 install pytest-django django requests
RUN git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/project-python-django-webapp
ADD test_server.py project-python-django-webapp
WORKDIR project-python-django-webapp

RUN pytest -v --ds=python_webapp_django.settings
```

No magic happens here - I used [an example Django project found on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/project-python-django-webapp/) to run the test for.

#### building the container

The container build starts the django server and executes the test, completing on test success:

```
$ docker build -t so/example .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 113a43faa138
Step 2/6 : RUN apt update && apt install git python3-pip -y && pip3 install pytest-django django requests
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd7adbe53cc8
Step 3/6 : RUN git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/project-python-django-webapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df514c1343c9
Step 4/6 : ADD test_server.py project-python-django-webapp
 ---> 118f74e43370
Step 5/6 : WORKDIR project-python-django-webapp
Removing intermediate container f81db838a81d
 ---> c3d35262f37c
Step 6/6 : RUN pytest -v --ds=python_webapp_django.settings
 ---> Running in e6292f2ac3e8
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
Django settings: python_webapp_django.settings (from command line option)
rootdir: /project-python-django-webapp, inifile:
plugins: django-3.3.2
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_server.py::test_index PASSED                                        [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 1.13 seconds ===========================
Removing intermediate container e6292f2ac3e8
 ---> c78c589b6d74
Successfully built c78c589b6d74
Successfully tagged so/example:latest
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one more base query :is there any disadvantage of live_server fixture as you mention it will create separate server instance in another thread

Comment: There's none that I knew of. The `live_server` fixture is `pytest`s pendant for the [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) which is usually used for system tests, and yours looks like a system test to me. However, for unit tests, the `client` fixture is more than enough, so `test_demo` would look like `def test_demo(client): assert client.get('/demo').status_code == 200`. Clean, simple and no need to use `requests`. Although there's nothing wrong with your test - don't get me wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a background process in a Dockerfile, or anything that looks like it.  In particular, the command

```
RUN python3 manage.py ... &
```

exits immediately, and when it does, the intermediate container with the background process is deleted.

I wouldn't try to run this sample code from inside the Dockerfile.  I'd end with

```
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Build and launch the image

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -p 8000:8000 myimage
```

Change the script to take the server location as an environment variable (0.0.0.0 is never a valid IP address to which to connect)

```
import requests
import os
def test_demo():
   response = requests.get(os.environ['SERVER_URL'] + '/demo')
   assert(response.status_code == 200)
```

and then run (assuming you're running the client from the same host)

```sh
SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8000 pytest
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, where i have to place this `SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8000 pytest` ??  After CMD in docker file

Comment: No, run the tests from your development system, outside Docker.

Comment: Is there any other way to runserver inside the docker file with pytest